# Constantly running web application

Tags: web, web-applications, trading, algorithmic-trading, forex

I want to build a constantly running forex trading application (even if the web page is not opened),
But I don't know what is the best way to do it, it's a software that should run constantly with constant internet connection, should I write it in Python as a PC application or web application ?, or is there anything better ?

Thank you for your support,

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any point of making a web application in your case. Architecture of algorithmic trading systems is a broad subject but most of the time it's an application which is only connected to a market data provider and a broker. A trading system can be built as a web application for example for browsing portfolio, historical trades or when some external events trigger trades but you should focus on the strategy itself rather than on a time consuming UI.

You should learn some basics from books/online course depending on your programming language but I think that Python is a great choice for rapid prototyping of strategies. You can also try some existing platforms like [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com/home) which can give a quick start for strategies testing.

Focus your efforts on thorough testing of the strategy because most of the time they look good on a paper but turn out to be an utter garbage in practice and without a strategy there is no need for an infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael , sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of technologies for developing "always on" scanners; I won't scour the internet for you; however, to give you an example, you can use something like [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions) -- it can run your scanner on a schedule.  It can be built with Python, if that's your language of choice.

Of course, there are a lot of third-party tools to choose from as well.